# Setting Struct Bounding Box Values

Tags: c++, parameters

I'm trying to create some bounding boxes around some objects that I have.

I create them like this:

```
struct boundingBox{
    float top;
    float bottom;
    float left;
    float right;
};
```

I'm having issues setting their values. I have this function which I was hoping would set their values:

```
void makeBoundingBox(boundingBox bound, float t, float b, float l, float r){
    bound.top =t;
    bound.bottom =b;
    bound.left=l;
    bound.right=r;
}
```

and I am trying to set them like this:

```
makeBoundingBox(car,b_Size,b_Size,b_Size,b_Size); //where car is a boundingBox object and b_Size is a calculated box size
```

When I'm using the above line, the values aren't set; I know this because I print to the console to check the values and they always come back `0`. However, if within the same function I use `makeBoundingBox`, I set `car.top = 500` manually instead, and print, the `car.top` is set successfully to 500 and works...

Does the `makeBoundingBox` method not work correctly by passing a struct object how I am expecting it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the box by value. For the routine to change the actual argument, pass it **by reference**. I.e.

```
void makeBoundingBox(boundingBox& bound, float t, float b, float l, float r){
    bound.top =t;
    bound.bottom =b;
    bound.left=l;
    bound.right=r;
}
```

---

However, instead of that, in C++11 just write

```
boundingBox{ 1, 1, 10, 10 }
```

when you need a `boundingBox` with those values.

---

In C++03 you can instead define a **constructor** for the `boundingBox` class.

Read up on that in your favorite C++ text book.

Here is an example class definition:

```
struct boundingBox{
    float top;
    float bottom;
    float left;
    float right;

    boundingBox( float a_top, float a_bottom, float a_left, float a_right )
        : top( a_top ), bottom( a_bottom )
        , left( a_left ), right( a_right )
    {}
};
```

and you can then create an instance like

```
boundingBox( 1, 1, 10, 10 )
```

---

As a general observation, using `float` instead of `double` can create some problems (especially with C++11 curly braces initialization), it has less precision than `double`, and it has no special advantages except where you need zillions of values, like a few billion.

So, use **`double`**.

That's the default floating point type in C++, e.g. it's the type of `3.14`.

Comment: I'm feeling very silly now. Thanks for taking the time to remind me. Great answer. Problem solved. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the `boundingBox` by value, not by reference. This means the `makeBoundingBox` function is operating on a local copy and changes do not propagate back to the original object.

Change your function definition as follows:

```
void makeBoundingBox(boundingBox& bound, float t, float b, float l, float r)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the struct to the function by VALUE, you need to pass by REFERENCE so:

```
void makeBoundingBox(boundingBox &bound, float t, float b, float l, float r){
    bound.top =t;
    bound.bottom =b;
    bound.left=l;
    bound.right=r;
}
```

Notice the & to pass by reference.

In your function call, do the same & in front of the variable name.

Comment: Or you could always return the struct instead of void:

`car = makeBoundingBox(b_Size,b_Size,b_Size,b_Size);`


`boundingBox makeBoundingBox(float t, float b, float l, float r){
    boundingBox bound;

    bound.top =t;
    bound.bottom =b;
    bound.left=l;
    bound.right=r;

    return bound;
}`

Comment: What syntax is used for returning it?

Comment: boundingBox return type on the function and assign the return value to car instead of just calling the function.  Exactly as I posted above, `car = makeBoundingBox(b_Size,b_Size,b_Size,b_Size);`

Comment: Where the function returns a type of boundingBox:)

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for clarifying that. I may convert them to returning it. Seems easier. Thanks for posting.